# How to use a external css file in my blog page in google blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a blog site @ google's blogger. Now I want to add my own styles in my pages. I have sufficient CSS knowledge to do this. But the problem is how do I save a css file, link it to my page and use in **Google blogger** it?

Note: I do not need to edit the blog template. I just need to add new styles to my page. E.G. : I need to create a code block by using codeBox class in my external style sheet file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, but i don't think you actually can't, google Blogger uses their own GUI and its made for people who don't really know how to code (that's one of the purpose of blogs).
I recommend you to host your site either on GitHub or you could host your own site vía a custom host.

Comment: Yup it is, you may search in youtube about GitHub hosting and i would use that instead of Google because it is WAY more customizable.

Comment: And it's pretty easy though.

Comment: This is possible. See separate answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and it is quite easy.
Simply edit your blogger theme HTML to incorporate the external .css file as you normally would.
You will, however, need to host the .css file on a separate server somewhere. I have my own server (which I use for another purpose) which works just fine. Or you could even host it using something like Google Drive.